# How to get parameters from URL in Liferay portlet?

Tags: java, portlet, liferay, jsr168

I'm using jsp of out-of-box portlet like feed.jspf in Liferay 6:

```
String articleId =null;
HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
articleId = httpReq.getParameter("articleId");
```

It is giving a null value whether in custom portlet or in .jsp files, but it should have a value.

Comment: Use RenderRequest request = (RenderRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("javax.portlet.request"); to get the RenderRequest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can always use the standard HttpServletRequest to retrieve your parameters from. You can get this request by using the PortalUtil class, like in the following example:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest);
String articleId = request.getParameter("articleId");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233585/different-jsp-rendering-in-liferay/39245456#39245456


Could you please look at my thread on the same theme and say if I can use same solution?

Answer (score 8):

In my Liferay- **JSP** I use this:

```
<!-- ... some imports... -->
<!-- ... some more imports... -->
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil" %>

<portlet:defineObjects /> <!-- Liferay-specific, defines renderRequest etc.-->

<%
    HttpServletRequest r = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);
    String wellHole =  PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(r).getParameter("well_hole");

%>
```

(this combines fragments of wisdom from other answers, notably Miguel Gil Martínez's  answer from 2012 Jul 23 at 17:35

Comment: is it possible to get it using JSTL or EL?

Answer (score 2):

When working with portlets, each HttpServletRequest paramenter has a prefix which informs the "type" of the parameter and a suffix expressing which *instance* of the portlet should process it. So, the name of the parameters is not just "articleId". I do not know what portlet are you working but if it was a portlet called, let's say, "example" deployed through a war the parameter would be called `example_WAR_exampleportletwar_articleId_w2Xd`.

However, you do not have to deal with such complexity. If you are working within a JSP of some already created portlet, there should be an object called `renderRequest` which contains all parameters and abstracts all this name mangling. So, instead of retrieving the original servlet requestion you an use it:

```
String articleId = renderRequest.getParamenter("articleId");
```

If this object is not defined, you just need to insert the `<portlet:defineObjects/>` tag somewhere and after this the object will be available.

HTH. Let us know if it worked!

Comment: ya that is right but i want to get articleId from url ...like  http://localhost:8080/author-detail?articleId=12345...can i get that in portlet ..jsp page???

Comment: So, does the URL parameter have no prefix or suffix, right? I do not know how to get it (I'd suggest to do what you tried anyway, hoping it works) but I wonder how this paramenter is set. How is it defined? Is it in some portlet/hook made by you?

Comment: From one of my custom portlet in liferay ...i'm calling other page by defining the name of the page and passing parameters manually...after it will redirect to author-detail page..in that i hv one portlet ..i hv to access articleId in that??....

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws 
  PortletException, IOException {

HttpServletRequest requestInsideThePortlet = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);

String myURLParam =
 PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(requestInsideThePortlet).getParameter("myURLParam");

....
....
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For JSF I use this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OriginalRequest {
    private HttpServletRequest getOriginalRequest() {
        return PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(
                PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(
                        (PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                .getExternalContext().getRequest() ) );
    }

    public String getParam( String name ) {
        return getOriginalRequest().getParameter( name );
    }

    public List<String> getParamNames() {
        return Collections.list( getOriginalRequest().getParameterNames() );
    }
}
```

Then in your facelet:

```
#{originalRequest.getParam('my_param')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried ur solutions but render request it gives me an exception,
so this is another solution:

```
public String obtainFromUrl(String keyFromWeb) {

    Object outcome = null;
    Map<String, Object> map = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    if (map != null) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(key) instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper) {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ((HttpServletRequestWrapper) map.get(key))
                        .getRequest();
                outcome = request.getParameter(keyFromWeb);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (String) outcome;

}
```