# Setting param from portlet URl into HttpServletRequest

Tags: url, parameters, render, portlet, liferay

I am referring to a url which has paramID from my portlet. The content of that paramID is handled in different portlet and it has its own controller.

That controller is taking HttpServletRequest to read that param.

```java
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
String paramID= request.getParameter("paramID");`
```

My param is in the url `http://mysite.com?paramID=123`

Will the HttpServletRequest read this param when I am calling using renderURL

```jsp
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="xyz" portletName="ABC" windowState="Normal"/>
...
<a href="xyz?pramID"> Click here</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="xyz?pramID"> Click here</a>` should be `<a href="xyz?paramID"> Click here</a>` There was a typo I suppose. Is it on this post only or in your code? You should check :)

Comment: @Mikko: The typo is here. I have it right in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with providing the param value while I invoked the renderURL

```jsp
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="xyz" portletName="ABC" windowState="Normal"/>
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

.....

```javascript
<JAVASCRIPT>
   var URL = NULL;       
   function(called){
          URL = "${xyz}&paramID=123"              //and this was read as servlet param
   }
</JAVASCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some information about render URL and such is under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906307/get-parameters-from-url-in-javaliferay) on its community wiki answer.

Also in some tutorial that is not on web I have read this kind of parameter passing is easiest done via session. Session is common for porlet and servlet so you don't have to think where the which parameter is visible and where not.